# For Loop over a list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a **train_file.txt** which has 3 columns on each row.

For example;

```
1 10 1

1 12 1

2 64 2

6 17 1

...
```

I am reading this txt file with

```
train_data = open("train_file.txt", 'r').readlines()
```

Then I am trying to get each value with for loop

```
for eachline in train_data:
    uid, lid, x = eachline.strip().split()
```

**Question**: Train data is a huge file that's why I want to just get the first 1000 rows.

I was trying to execute the following code but I am getting an error ('list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer)

```
for eachline in range(train_data,1000)
        uid, lid, x = eachline.strip().split()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not necessary to read the entire file at all. You could use `enumerate` on the file directly and break early or use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

train_data = list(islice(open("train_file.txt", 'r'), 1000))
```

You can also keep using the same file handle to read more data later:

```
f = open("train_file.txt", 'r')
train_data = list(islice(f, 1000)) # reads first 1000
test_data = list(islice(f, 100))   # reads next 100
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try changing this line:

```
train_data = open("train_file.txt", 'r').readlines()
```

To:

```
train_data = open("train_file.txt", 'r').readlines()[:1000]
```

Answer (score 2):

`train_data` is a list, use slicing:
`for eachline in train_data[:1000]:`

As the file is "huge" in your words a better approach is to read just first 1000 rows (`readlines()` will read the whole file in memory)

```
with open("train_file.txt", 'r'):
    train_data = []
    for idx, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        train_data.append(line.strip.split())
        if idx == 1000:
            break
```

Note that data will be `str`, not `int`. You probably want to convert them to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use enumerate and a break:

```
for k, line in enumerate(lines):
    if k > 1000: 
        break # exit the loop

    # do stuff on the line
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `csv` built in library since the data is csv-like (or the pandas one if you're using it), and using `with`. So something like this:

```py
import csv
from itertools import islice

with open('./test.csv', 'r') as input_file:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=' ')
  rows = list(islice(csv_reader, 1000))

# Use rows
print(rows)
```

You don't need it right now but it will make escaped characters or multiline entries way easier to parse. Also, if there are headers you can use `csv.DictReader` to include them.

Regarding your original code:

- The call the `readlines()` will read all lines at that point so doing any filtering after won't make a difference.
- If you did read it that way, to get the first 1000 lines your `for` loop should be:

```py
for eachline in traindata[:1000]:
  ...
```